# In Node Editor, why is the RGB Curve Node different?

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves

My RGB Curve node looks like this:
[image: my RGB Curve]

But on most of the tutorials it looks like this:
[image: their RGB Curve]

They have the black and white channels.  I upgraded from blender 2.77 to 2.78, and I tried toggling between cycles render and blender render.  How do I get the node they are looking at?

Comment: You are totally right, when I go to compositing view (instead of expanding new windows in default view), I get the second node.  Thank you!

Comment: @3pointedit You need to '@' people, e.g. '@Cegaton'.

Comment: @Cegatron I think that you should make this reply an answer for others with the same confusion ;-) Thanks ray-maillot for the tip although I can't @ you in same reply

Answer (score 4):

The first image is from the material nodes.

[image]

The second is from the compositor nodes.

[image]

[image]

The curve editor in the Compositor works differently, it has additional controls to determine the ranges for the curve.

From the [Blender Manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/rgb_curves.html)

> **Black Level**
>
> Defines the input color that is (linear) mapped to black.
>
> **White Level**
>
> Defines the input color that is (linear) mapped to white